# Understanding notation regarding phase oracle

Tags: quantum-state, unitarity, oracles

I am new to quantum computing. I cannot get my head around the following:
Consider a finite random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow E$ on a probability space $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, P)$. Let $H_{\Omega}$ be a Hilbert space with basis states ${|\omega\rangle}{\omega \in \Omega}$. We say that a unitary $P_X$ acting on $H_{\Omega} \otimes \mathbb{C}^d$ is a phase oracle for $X$ if
$$P_X:∣\omega⟩∣j⟩ \rightarrow e^{iX(\omega)_j}∣\omega⟩∣j⟩$$

for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $j \in [d]$

I do not understand, why $∣j⟩$ is a vector and simultaneously a scalar index in $X(\omega)_j$ Can anybody explain the difference to me?