# Understanding notation regarding phase oracle continued

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, unitarity

Since I am not able to comment on my post, I had to register an account and start a new post. Maybe my old post can be deleted, which is found : [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32889/understanding-notation-regarding-phase-oracle)

I am new to quantum computing. I cannot get my head around the following:
Consider a finite random variable $X : \Omega \rightarrow E$ on a probability space $(\Omega, 2^{\Omega}, P)$. Let $H_{\Omega}$ be a Hilbert space with basis states ${|\omega\rangle}{\omega \in \Omega}$. We say that a unitary $P_X$ acting on $H_{\Omega} \otimes \mathbb{C}^d$ is a phase oracle for $X$ if
$$P_X:∣\omega⟩∣j⟩ \rightarrow e^{iX(\omega)_j}∣\omega⟩∣j⟩$$

for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $j \in [d]$

I do not understand, why $∣j⟩$ is a vector and simultaneously a scalar index in $X(\omega)_j$ Can anybody explain the difference to me?

Now I think $∣j⟩$ is just on of the the basis vectors denoted by a index, which some kind of abuse of notation.

The following answers was given:
Different j's in the second register lead to different phase shifts of $|\omega⟩$.

I do not quite understand this. Isn't the whole basis state $∣\omega⟩∣j⟩$ seen as tensor product shifted in phase?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Do you know what phase kickback is? Also, from where are you getting your example?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli:  No I do not. But I did understand that the e-part shifts the phase of the state $ |\omega| \otimes |j>$

Comment: Maybe $|j>$ denotes the j-th basis vector in $\mathbb{C}^d$,so each of the basis vectors in the tensor product space are shifted in phase?

Comment: Something like that I think.  The way you've written things $j$ is just a number in $[d]$, and you can do a controlled rotation of $\mid\omega\rangle$ by a phase amount $X^{\omega_j}$.  Different $j$'s in the second register lead to different phase shifts of $\mid\omega\rangle$.

Comment: Yes but $X(\omega)_j$ depends on both $\omega$ and $j$. I'm assuming that you calculate - perhaps in ancilla registers - the amount of phase shift, based on both $\omega$ and $j$.

Comment: Where did this definition of $P_X$ come from? (I'm suspecting a typo. Perhaps it should be $e^{i X(\omega) j}$?)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.09787.pdf Page 7. it is not a typo. How can it be explained then?